# Does sliced array leave a tuple? Need to use array slice as integer but int() won't work

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, int, tuples

I'm using this simple function to determine the gradient on a function using numerical methods.

```
    def f_prime((x,y),delta=0.1):
    '''Numerically derive the gradient of f(x,y).'''
        x = int((x,y)[:1])
        y = int((x,y)[1:])
        df_dx = (f((x+delta,y))-f((x-delta,y)))/(2*delta)
        df_dy = (f((x,y+delta))-f((x,y-delta)))/(2*delta)
    return numpy.array((df_dx,df_dy))
```

This gives the error feedback:

```
    File "J:\...\.py", line 32, in f_prime
    def f_prime((x,y),delta=0.1):
    TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Any ideas how I've made it a tuple and how not to do so? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(1, 2)[1:]
#>>> (2,)

(1, 2)[1]
#>>> 2
```

You're slicing instead of indexing; slicing returns a sub-collection whereas indexing returns an item.

Comment: Brilliant! So simple, thanks. But now I get another error in the same bit of code: df_dx = (f((x+delta,y))-f((x-delta,y)))/(2*delta)
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the slice index (x,y)[:1] like you did in your code, you get a sliced tuple. You have to specify exact index, or unpack your tuple directly into your variables if you know how many values are there in your tuple (which probably, should be the case):

```
def f_prime(t, delta=0.1):
'''Numerically derive the gradient of f(x,y).'''
    x, y = map(int, t)
    df_dx = (f((x+delta,y))-f((x-delta,y)))/(2*delta)
    df_dy = (f((x,y+delta))-f((x,y-delta)))/(2*delta)
return numpy.array((df_dx,df_dy))
```